# In using Ant Design's <Icon/> what are acceptable arguments for the attribute "type"?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using React UI library antd. For `<Icon/>` there is an attribute "type"

Example:

```
<Icon type="edit"/>
```

renders an edit icon.

I cannot find where in the docs the accepted values for this attribute are defined....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you are using ant with version 3.x. this is list of all icon 
https://3x.ant.design/components/icon/

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is sparse in this case, but it seems the values are the icon names, you can find a full list of icons in the [Antd GitHub repo](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design-icons/tree/master/packages/icons-svg/svg/filled)